# Why "pensions products"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, attributive-nouns, compound-nouns

[The Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cross-sell) has a sentence:

> They can cross-sell to the bank's existing customers and introduce life insurance and **pensions products**.

**Pension**, though a count noun, here functions as an attributive noun modifying *products*. Then why is it in the plural? Shouldn't attributive nouns be in the singular, such as "*pension plans*"? As far as I know there seem to be some exceptions where a plural noun precedes another noun to form a compound noun phrase, but pension doesn't seem to be one of them, according to [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pension_2). Google suggests both **pension products** and **pensions products** are in use, the former more popular. Any chance this would be a BrE/AmE difference?

Answer (score 1):

This may indeed be a British idiosyncrasy.  I would consider it a typo if I read it in the US.

The only way I can think of to make sense of it is to consider "life insurance and pensions" to be a named category or department that always uses that tense.  For example

> that is a mergers and acquisitions product

makes sense because "mergers and acquisitions" is a single department in an investment bank and always uses the plural, even when it's used as a modifier.  I could easily imagine "life insurance and pensions" to be a similar department.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a speaker of AmE and *wouldn't* consider **pensions products** necessarily a typo, since  we do see the plural noun adjunct fairly often, especially in the financial sector.  I'd give the text the benefit of the doubt.

> The SEC warns consumers that some sellers of **[annuities products](https://www.ag.state.mn.us/Consumer/Publications/AnnuitiesUnsuitableInvforSeniors.asp)** urge
>   customers to switch to another annuity, a practice called “churning.”