# "Culture" or "Cultures" for Proper-Noun?

Tags: spelling, proper-nouns

What is the correct spelling for the name of a place below?

> a) Asia Culture Museum
> b) Asia Cultures Museum

Comment: In Thailand there is the "[Asian Culture Museum](https://asianculturesmuseum.org/)".   And in Texas there is the [Texas Asian Cultures Museum](https://www.texasasianculturesmuseum.org/)  Which one are your asking about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "pensions products"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180687/why-pensions-products)

Comment: According to James's link, the proper name of the second one is _Texas State Museum of Asian Cultures_.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a proper noun then its spelling is fixed and you are not at liberty to vary it. For instance I cannot decide to write *The Lincoln Center* as *The Lincoln Centre* just because that it how it would be spelled if it were in York (UK) rather than where it actually is, New York.